# Let $\,f$ be a real differentiable function defined on $\,[a,b]$,where the derivative is an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $\,f$ be a real differentiable function defined on $\,[a,b]$,where the derivative is an increasing function and $x_0 \in [a,b]$. Then which of the following statements is **correct**?
>
> 1. $f(x) \le f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0), \forall x \in [a,b]$
> 2. $f(x) \ge f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0), \forall x \in [a,b]$

*My Attempt*: Since $f'(x)$ is an increasing function $\forall x \in [a,b]$, $\frac{d}{dx}f'(x) \ge 0$ and so at $x_0, \frac{d}{dx}f'(x_0) \ge 0 \implies \lim_{x \to x_0} {{f'(x)-f'(x_0)}\over {x-x_0}} \ge 0$ and I am stuck and could not get rid of limit.

Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't know that you can differentiate $f$ twice. But, you do know that $f(x) = f(x_0)+(x-x_0) f'(c)$ for some $c \in (x_0,x)$ (why!?). So, can you say which inequality is correct for $f(x_0) + (x-x_0)f'(c)$ based on the increasing nature of $f'$?

Comment: thanks for the explanation.I think option 2 is the  right choice but still i need further clarification. Can you add few more details?

Comment: Note that I assumed that $x > x_0$ when I applied the mean value theorem. The point is that if $c > x_0$ then $f'(c) \geq f'(x_0)$ and use this inequality in the expression $f(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_0)f'(c)$. If $x < x_0$, you can still find a $c \in (x,x_0)$ and have the same equality $f(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_0)f'(c)$, but in this case $c < x_0$ and so $f'(c) \leq f'(x_0)$.